# Changing the size of ScrollView not working within the tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So this is how my app currently looks like http://gyazo.com/f26ecd3a9d173ab76ee86946cd7a152c , when I click on More... (UIButton) the scrollView becomes slightly longer but the TableView still keeps the same size http://gyazo.com/f9f36c5b308f209d81d5a75b430eeb03 , and when I start scrolling again everything goes back to normal like the first picture showed (the scrollView goes to it's original size).

```
- (IBAction)moreInfo:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 184);
    }];
    [sender setTitle:@"Less..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Any ideas of how I could make the scrollView become bigger and stay big even though you scroll in the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to adjust the height of `cell` in `UITableView` DataSource.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Because you reuse the `cell` inside `tableview`